# Multiple Elasticsearch Indexes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I have a staging & production instance of a Rails 3 application (using the tire gem) on the same Ubuntu server. It appears that both of these instances are sharing the same elasticsearch index which obviously isn't what I want.

How can I get my production and staging instances to use separate instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need override the index name. Assuming you're tying into ActiveRecord it will create an index name based on the model in question. You could adjust the name with a prefix like so;

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  index_prefix "#{Rails.env}" 

  ...
```

which would then create an index named `development_articles`, `production_articles` etc. It's important the the `index_prefix` comes after the Tire includes.

Or alternatively rename the index entirely

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  index_name "My-Development-Article-Index" 

  ...
```