# how to run multiple instances of elasticsearch on one host

Tags: elasticsearch

I have several machines each with 128 GB of ram, each host is running a single instance of Elasticsearch. 
I would like to run another data node on each host and allocate around 30 GB to the jvm heap.

I know I have to create a separate config file .yml and data directory..etc. My question is do I need to modify the service wrapper so that each node will be started/ stopped seperatly?

I am running ES version 1.3 on Centos 6.5

thank you

Comment: Why do this instead of running bigger single ES JVMs per host?

Comment: Because of [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#compressed_oops), @MattBall.

Comment: jvm Garbage collection is more efficient when heap is < 32 GB

Comment: By service wrapper do you mean the init.d script?  if so, yes it makes sense to have one init.d script for each node - duplicate the file for each node and modify the sysconfig, lock file and pid lines.

Comment: Ah – your question didn't initially include the 128 GB figure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple nodes in ElasticSearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477303/multiple-nodes-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: @Olly Cruickshank I currently use sudo service elasticsearch start , which starts the first instance, I wanted to know whether I will need somthing like sudo service elasticsearch2 start to start the second node.

Comment: thanks Paul Sanwald that is a good link, but it does not  show how to start the different instances as a service. it shows how to run each node manually.

Comment: @Yasir - you'll need to copy `/etc/init.d/elastcsearch` to `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch2` to set up the additional service and modify the file as I described. Also lookup **chkconfig** to see how to automatically start the service when your server starts.

Comment: thanks Olly, I have got the file in /etc/rc.d/init.d/elasticsearch but not sure where the parameters are passed in for the es_config, es_home etc on this line;</br>  `daemon --user $ES_USER --pidfile $pidfile $exec -p $pidfile -d -Des.default.path.home=$ES_HOME -Des.default.path.logs=$LOG_DIR -Des.default.path.data=$DATA_DIR -Des.default.path.work=$WORK_DIR -Des.default.path.conf=$CONF_DIR`

Answer (score 10):

You need to prepare two elasticsearch.yml config files to configure settings accordingly and specify these files when startup up the two nodes.

```
bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.1.yml
bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.2.yml
```

At least the following should be set differently for the two nodes:

```
http.port
transport.tcp.port
path_data
path_logs
path_pid
node.name
```

The following needs to point to the **other** in both files to allow the nodes to find each other:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: '127.0.0.1:9302'
```

EDIT: the property is now deprecated, look at : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-settings.html

See [this blog](https://codeascraft.com/2014/12/04/juggling-multiple-elasticsearch-instances-on-a-single-host/) and [this discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-i-run-multiple-elasticsearch-nodes-on-the-same-machine/67)

Comment: why should the `cluster.name` be set differently?

Comment: you are right, that is not useful, I have adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

elasicsearch.yml-1

```
cluster.name: test
node.name: node-1
path.data: /Users/musab/Desktop/elasticsearch/data
path.logs: /Users/musab/Desktop/elasticsearch/logs
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 4
```

elasicsearch.yml-2

```
cluster.name: test
node.name: node-1
path.data: /Users/musab/Desktop/elasticsearch/data
path.logs: /Users/musab/Desktop/elasticsearch/logs
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 4
```

[image]