# How to create multiple node for multiple application using single ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to create 3 different nodes for 2 separate applications for each in one machine. First, I tried to create 3 nodes in my ES for "production", "development", "testing" using the command:

```
bin/elasticsearch -Epath.data=data1 -Epath.logs=log1
```

My elasticsearch.yml file located at admin:///etc/elasticsearch and getting error as:

```
bash: bin/elasticsearch: No such file or directory
```

Besides, I also tried modifying elasticsearch.yml file following questions answers but failed.

[How to add a new node to my Elasticsearch cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717790/how-to-add-a-new-node-to-my-elasticsearch-cluster)

[Multiple nodes in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477303/multiple-nodes-in-elasticsearch)

But I can not create separate nodes. My purpose is to test my application separately so that it doesn't affect the main node.
Here are respentive lines of my elasticsearch.yml file:

```
cluster.name : scidatamanager
node.name : "dev"
node.name : "test"
node.master: true
node.data: false
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]

cluster.name : scidatamanager
node.name : "test"
node.master: false
node.data: true
http.port: 9201
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.2"]

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
```

I have also asked the same thing elasic discussion forum([Here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-create-multiple-node-in-one-cluster/266227)).

Answer (score 0):

While starting the ES instance, you can specify the node as follow:

```
bin/elasticsearch -E node:node1
```

For another node:

```
bin/elasticsearch -E node:node2
```

This will bring up two ES nodes, in same cluster.
There is no need to make changes to yml file as the new node will start on different port by default.